# Cannot determine why pointer variable will not address elements in a string in this program?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am attempting to utilize a pointer variable to access elements of a string and there are issues with my code generating a compilation error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 29

char arrayI[250];
char *ptr;

int main(void)
{
ptr = arrayI;

puts("Enter string to arrayI: up to 29 chars:\n");
fgets(arrayI, MAX, stdin);

printf("\n Now printing array by pointer:\n");
printf("%s", *ptr);


ptr = arrayI[1];     //(I set the pointer to the second array char element)
printf("%c", *ptr);  //Here is where I was wanting to use my pointer to 
                     //point to individual array elements.
return 0;
}
```

My compiler crieth:

[Warning] assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

I do not see where my pointer was ever assigned to the integer data type? Could someone please explain why my attempt to implement a pointer variable is failing? Thanks all!

Comment: in the second printf you have %s which actually takes a pointer ---
should be printf("%s", ptr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
ptr = arrayI[1];     //(I set the pointer to the second array char element)
printf("%c", *ptr);
```

is broken. `ptr` is a variable of type `char*`, and you're trying to assign a `char` to it. You want to assign the address of `arrayI[1]` to `ptr`, and you should thus use `ptr = &arrayI[1];`.

EDIT -- As Catalyst noted, your second printf should read as follows: `printf("%s", ptr`).

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 29
// An array declaration that can hold upto 250 characters 
char arrayI[250];
// A pointer variable that can hold the address of a character
char *ptr;
int main(void)
{
   // Assigning the array's base address to the pointer variable
   ptr = arrayI;
   puts("Enter string to arrayI: up to 29 chars:\n");
   fgets(arrayI, MAX, stdin);

   printf("\n Now printing array by pointer:\n");
   // Printing the entire array
   printf("%s", ptr);

   // Now modifying the pointer variable to point to the second character
   ptr = &arrayI[1];     
   // Printing the second character from left in the array
   printf("%c", *ptr);  
}
```

Suppose that the memory is allocated as follows:

Assume the base address starts from 4000.

```
      +----------+
4000  |          |    arrayI[0]  
      +----------+
4001  |          |    arrayI[1]
      +----------+
4002  |          |    arrayI[2]
      +----------+
           .
           .
           .
      +----------+
4249  |          |    arrayI[249]
      +----------+

Now ptr = arrayI => 4000

printf("%s",ptr);  //Print the entire string starting from address 4000

Now ptr = &arrayI[1] => 4001

printf("%c", *ptr); // Print valueAt(ptr) => valueAt(4001) => second character of arrayI
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the line "ptr = arrayI[1]". ptr is of type char*, while arrayI[1] is of type char (which in C is the same as an int, hence the compiler message). The fix should be changing this line to *ptr = arrayI[1];

Comment: Two things: `char` and `int` are two different types, and C knows this. Also, if he uses `*ptr = arrayI[1]`, then it'll set `arrayI[0]` to `array[1]`, which is clearly not intended.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will be needing this

```
ptr = arrayI;

puts("Enter string to arrayI: up to 29 chars:\n");
fgets(arrayI, MAX, stdin);

printf("\n Now printing array by pointer:\n");
printf("%s", ptr);


ptr = arrayI+1;     //(Where 1 is the sizeof char)
printf("%c", *ptr)
```

`ptr` is a pointer,`arrayI` is also a pointer,but `arrayI[1]` is a character aka integer.

Comment: Using `arrayI + 1` overcomplicates `arrayI[1]`. Also, `arrayI` is NOT a pointer. `arrayI` is an array. http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=aryptr